# How to show that a set is not complete (logic)

Tags: logic, proof-writing

By complete I mean that any other Boolean operation can be represented just by using the connectives in the set in question. I get that we could show that a set is complete by showing formulas for all. But how could we show it is not complete as I don't know how to prove it would be impossible to write a formula./

For example, to show that $\{\cup,\cap\}$ is not complete, I assume that I would need to show that there exists a Boolean function that cant be represented by only these symbols.

If it were to be complete, it would have to be 1 complete in particular, so I would have to be able to form True, False, the identity, and the negation.

But I don't know how I can show it cannot be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: meet and join are monotonic. Negation is not monotonic. Composites of monotonic operations are monotonic. So negation cannot be defined as a composite of meets and joins.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this, can you explain what you mean by they are monotonic?

Comment: An operation is monotonic with respect to an ordering if increasing the operands cannot decrease the value of the operation. If you order the truth values by $\mathsf{false}\ < \mathsf{true}$, then you will see that negation is not monotonic but any operation formed by composing meet and join is.

Comment: Thanks but say that p1 and p2 are true, then p1 AND p2 is true, but what if p3 is false? then p1 AND p2 AND p3 is false? so what part am I confusing?

Comment: By increasing do you mean more variable or literally increasing from a truth value of 0 to 1?

Comment: If you are writing $0$ for false and $1$ for true, then I mean literally increasing (or more precisely non-decreasing). E.g., in your second formula, changing $p_3$ from true to false is allowed to change the formula from true to false, but changing it from false to true is not allowed to have that effect. $p_1 \land p_2$ and $p_1 \land p_2 \land p_3$ are just two different formulas and the monotonicity condition isn't asking you to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

A set of operators is functionally complete if and only if it is not a subset of any of the following classes:

- Monotonic, which means "increase" some of the inputs from 0 to 1 will never "decrease" the output from 1 to 0. e.g. $\lor, \land, \top, \bot$.
- Affine, which means the input will never or always affect the output. e.g. $\neg, \top, \bot, \leftrightarrow, \nleftrightarrow$.
- Self-dual, equal to their dual. e.g. $\neg$.
- Truth-preserving, preserve truth. e.g. $\lor, \land, \top, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow$.
- Falsity-preserving, preserve falsity. e.g. $\lor, \land, \bot, \nrightarrow, \nleftrightarrow$.

So to show a set is not functionally complete, it is sufficient to show it's a subset of any of these 5 classes.